# Is it permissible to develop online games which consume a lot of time?

Tags: sharia, game

Some people spend a lot of time on playing online games. 
So is it ok for a Muslim to develop such  an online game and earn money from that game?

Answer (score 1):

[image: bismillah]

Spending the time to that are not useful it does not allowed in islam.

described in surah [Al-`Aşr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Asr) 1-3 (The Declining Day, The Time) - سورة العصر

[image]

By time,

[image]

Indeed, mankind is in loss,

[image]

Except for those who have believed and done righteous deeds and advised each other to truth and advised each other to patience.

"Allah takes an oath by time, the passage of night and day, the time in which man works his deeds: “By Time,” the purpose of the oath being “Truly man is in a state of loss,” loss has many different levels: complete loss, the state of one who loses both this world and the Hereafter, who loses eternal bliss and instead deserves Hell. A person could also lose out in some aspects and not others and this is why Allah generalises this loss to all of man save those who have four qualities: “Not so those who believe” in what Allah as ordered to believe in, faith cannot come about or be complete without knowledge and therefore it is a branch of knowledge, “and do good works,” all good deeds, outward and inward, those linked to the rights of Allah and the rights of His servants, both the obligatory and recommended “and counsel one another to truth” which is faith and righteous deeds “and counsel one another to patience,” in obedience to Allah, away from disobedience to Him, and in the face of His decrees that man finds trying. The first two matters perfect the servant and the next two aid to perfect others. In the completion of these four matters lies safety from loss and through them does the servant attain success"

```
So is it ok for a Muslim to develop such an online game and earn money from that game?
```

it is allowed if the result of your job and your ideas.

described in Sahih Muslim Hadith 6251     Narrated by Abu Hurayrah

Allah's Messenger (The prophet muhammad) said: ‘Do you know who is a ‘muflis’ (abjectly poor or one who is totally bankrupt)?’ They (the Companions (r.a.) of the Prophet (saws)) said: ‘A ‘muflis’ amongst us is one who has neither dirham with him nor wealth.’ He (the Prophet (saws)) said: ‘The ‘muflis’ of my Ummah would be he who would come on the Day of Resurrection with prayers and fasts and Zakah but (he would find himself bankrupt on that day as he would have exhausted his funds of virtues) since he hurled abuses upon others, brought calumny against others, unlawfully consumed the wealth of others, shed the blood of others, and beat others. His virtues would be credited to the account of one (who suffered at his hand). And if his good deeds fall short to clear the account (of his mis-deeds), then their sins would be entered in (his account) and he would be thrown in the Hell-Fire!’

It is not allowed if plowing result of the work other people.

described in Surah Al-Baqarah : 188 (The Cow) - سورة البقرة

[image]

"And do not consume one another's wealth unjustly or send it [in bribery] to the rulers in order that [they might aid] you [to] consume a portion of the wealth of the people in sin, while you know [it is unlawful]"

Comment: Sholohin: 
>it is allowed if the result of your job and your ideas.

how about this, I make a game, people play, and if they want they can buy something inside that game. Some of them will spend a lot of hours playing it, which is bad, someone won't. Some of the will buy things. In this case, does my intention to make such a game and also if I do it, then the money I get from it is OK?

Comment: sure it's ok. It's not your fault if people buy your game, then they spend their time with your games because they do not know how to use their time.